# full featured debugger for javascript and ExtJS

Tags: javascript, debugging, extjs

I want to write a web application that uses ExtJS Javascript and PHP in the back end, I need a tool that help me to debug javascript also set break points while executing

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: other than firebug because I need to set break point if possible ?

Comment: But you **can** set break points in firebug.

Comment: oh ok  Chau please tell me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Zend studio 8.x supports JavaScript debugging, break points and content assist for some js frameworks such as extjs, prototype, Jquery and Dojo.
   Read more on Zend studio on http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/studio-whats-new#jsdebug You may download a free trial from [here](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/downloads)
   and use it for free for 90days.This is the ideal solution if you are willing to develop using PHP and html and JavaScript.
2. You may have an eye on [spket](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/downloads) IDE too. http://spket.com/javascript-editor.html it's feature rich and you could integrate it into eclipse based IDE`s such as Zend Studio.
3. [Jetbrains webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/#JavaScript) has some great features including break points and you may get a free download and use it for 30days for free.